# What are the numbers next to player names?

Tags: titanfall

In the lobby there are tags with numbers on against some player names - what are they?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this Gen system in multiplayer and how does it work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166379/what-is-this-gen-system-in-multiplayer-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @svick That [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166379/4797) was asked after this one. The dupe should probably be the other way around.

Comment: @galacticninja http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic

Comment: @Frank Are you saying that this question is the one that should have been closed? This older question already has an answer with 5 upvotes. While at the time of writing of that meta post, "*It should also be noted that [the older question] doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.*" Also, as per the top-voted answer in that meta post, "*the first question to reach that criteria (either a definitively upvoted answer and/or an accepted answer) should be treated as the 'master' question and all others closed as a duplicate of that question.*"

Comment: @galacticninja The argument you were using was, "This one's older, therefore the other one should be closed."  I am directly refuting that, and based on the questions themselves, the other one looks to be much higher quality.  And double-checking the answers, that is also true.  Age is not a defense against duping.  *Quality* is.

Comment: @Frank [retroactive duplication is monstruous](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-is-asked-which-is-a-collection-of-other-asked-que#comment23087_7901) .Even thouh I agree the other question is better quality than this one. This question was and is still a perfectly valid question and it shouldnt be closed because someone else asked it in a better way.

Comment: @WizLiz Indeed it is.  That has nothing to do with this, however, because nothing is being duped retroactively.  We should be keeping the higher quality questions and answers open, as that serves the site better. In an ideal world, we would have caught the other before it got an answer, and then duped it to this one.  Since it slipped through the cracks, though, and garnered a better answer than this one, that makes it better than this one, therefore this one should be duped.

Comment: @Frank My argument is: this question's older *and* already has an upvoted answer. (currently 5 upvotes). We are establishing a bad precedent if we allow newer duplicate questions of older *already answered* questions simply because they are deemed to be better quality by a user. The 'quality' of a question is subjective. Its upvote count isn't. Users who deem the original question to be low quality could edit it to be better.

Comment: @galacticninja Even with that argument, the other answer has MORE upvotes.  Which means it's higher quality, by your standards.  Why should this question be kept, when all indicators show the other is better?  As I said, in an ideal world, we would've duped the other to this one once it cropped up.  Since we didn't, keeping the higher quality one benefits the site more.

Comment: @Frank I said nothing about equating the quality of a post to its number of upvotes. Like I said earlier, quality is subjective, so it shouldn't be used as a deciding factor in this case. What I'm saying is: this question was asked *first*, got an upvoted answer *first*, and hence, should be the original. There's nothing subjective about that.

Comment: @galacticninja And, as always, *age* means absolutely nothing at all.  *Quality* is what matters.  It might be subjective, but according to the upvotes, the other answer is higher quality.  Either way, this needs to be moved into a meta discussion.

Answer (score 6):

These tags show what "Generation" the player has achieved in the game, which is done by leveling up to level 50 and completing specific challenges for each generation, then "regenerating" back to level 1.

Comment: Think of this also like "Prestige" in the Call of Duty series of games.  Though I'm not sure if all of your unlocks reset in Titanfall or not when you do this.

Comment: @Mkalafut - It does.  You lose everything except your Burn Cards and the Titans.  This means all guns, abilties, and skil unlocks are lost.

Comment: @Ramhound I figured as much.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of adornments that can go next to a player's name: Generation markers and Rank markers.

#### Generation Markers

Once you reach Level 50, you can "Regenerate" upon completing certain challenges, like achieving a certain number of kills with a particular weapon or winning a set number of matches in a particular mode. You lose all unlocks, upgrades, and achievements (you keep your Burn Cards, though), and are set to Level 1, but are given a bonus XP modifier and a tag next to your name indicating which regeneration you're now on. This is akin to "Prestiging" in Call of Duty. There are 10 Regeneration levels.

#### Rank Markers

If you choose to activate your Rank Chip, your Regeneration marker is replaced by a Rank Marker. This starts at Bronze 1, as denoted by a worn, bronze-colored marker with the Roman numeral "I", and increases as you gain rank points. There are five levels in each tier, labelled "I-V". There are also five tiers: Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum, and Diamond.

If a player is not using a Rank Chip and is Generation 1, there will be no adornment next to that player's name.